# What is the best way to create navigation in the app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am wondering what the best practice is about navigation on iOS apps. As I know, you can do it in three ways: navigation bar, tab bar or custom buttons. There are pros and cons for each of them but I would like to know what is the best way of doing it in terms of easiness, integrity of it with the app and flexibility.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no right answer, it depends on the app and your preferences.

Comment: yes, i know that. thats why i would like to hear the experiences of people who used each of them and learn which one to focus in my app.

Comment: Again, it all depends on what your app does, how it does it, and how it's structured. From a backend perspective, both the navigation controller and the tab controller work fine. I would recommend against custom buttons, because I did that in my first app, and maintenance was a nightmare. Tab controllers are usually used to switch between navigation controllers. Are you sure you weren't thinking of master-detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will all depend on how your app functions, what it is meant to do, etc. Each of the methods of navigation mentioned in your question can all be used in conjunction with one another to meet the needs your specific app. It is best to assess what exactly your app needs and then decide on the method of navigation based on your design. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: this definitely helps. thanks! do you have any article or resource where i can find the differences between these methods? i think i know some of the differences but would like to check any extensive resource about it

Comment: I don't have a specific article but I'm sure apples documentation will give you a good idea of the similarities and differences between them

Comment: thanks, appreciated!